# Questions about the get and set methods in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is an example of the use of `get` and `set`:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Fetus',
        age: 0,
        children: []
    },
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Welcome to this world");
    },
    adopt: function( newChildsName ){
        var children_array = this.get("children");
        children_array.push( newChlidsName );
        this.set({ children: children_array });
    }
});

var person = new Person({
    name: "Thomas",
    age: 67,
    children: ['Ryan']
});

var age = person.get("age");
var name = person.get("name");
var children = person.get("children");
```

1. I would like to know if these methods are part of Backbone.js, Underscore.js, or JavaScript?
2. Why in Backbone.js you do this: `person.set({ age: 67});` instead of this: `person.age="age";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Backbone.
2. Because calling a method (`person.set({ age: 67});`) instead of setting a property (`person.age="age";`) allows Backbone to do more things behind the scenes than simply changing the value of `age`. It will for example update the content in your views.

Answer (score 2):

We've added Backbone model getters and setters that do exactly what you want. See [this code](https://gist.github.com/1538645). It's supported on modern browsers, but older ones are out of the question.

The reason is that setting properties doesn't trigger events, whereas setting values via functions enables it to trigger events that Backbone requires to function properly.